escalating what?
Respiratory causes such as asthma or chronic obstructive pulmonary disease are treated with short- or long-term bronchodilators, escalating the use of steroids and adjuncts based on clinical discretion
What is meant by ‘escalating’ in this sentence? it doesn't look like a cause and effect sentence? it has a passive structure but I didn't understand it exactly. if you can help me, I would appreciate i

escalating the use of steroids and adjuncts means causing the use of steroids and adjuncts to increase. And what's causing that effect is [treatment using] short- or long-term bronchodilators.

...But it's causes within causes within causes, given that the entire paragraph is about "causes of tachypnea!. Anyway, the structure of "[comma] escalating..." is semantically equivalent to starting a new sentence there with "This escalates..."

then we can say that this sentence is a cause-effect sentence, right?

I don't know exactly what you understand by "a cause-effect sentence", or why that's a useful concept in learning English, but maybe it is. But like I say, there are at least three levels of "cause" here. The entire paragraph addresses causes of tachypnea (such as asthma), within which tachypnea "causes" (leads to)  treatment with bronchodilators. And that treatment causes the escalation. It's "causes all the way down"! :)

Yes, that's exactly it :) Cause-effect is very important on the GMAT exam.

Well, with that sentence, you might struggle to identify which cause (and which effect) is most important from the perspective of the examiners!

I believe this could be an error for "escalating to..." if my understanding is correct that bronchodilators are not steroidal.  In other words, if the bronchodilators don't work, or don't work as well as needed, treatment can then escalate to steroid use

They want a good gmat score to apply for a master's degree for the Liverpool University Surgery Department, and as you said, GMAT is a little difficult exam. :) thanks to you I'm learning a lot and I'm grateful for that.

@TimR: I'm no medic, but I think it's unlikely that the use of steroids and adjuncts is the final and most extreme treatment for asthma (if and when bronchodilators fail to effect a cure). Besides which, ...escalating to [desperate measures] wouldn't be very good phrasing, imho.

@FumbleFingers  Who said anything about final or most extreme?   Steroids can have more side-effects.

@emilywenly   Grammatically the original sentence is somewhat broken:  "are treated with ... escalating steroids".  What is needed is an intransitive form of escalate.  I believe the author means to say that treatment may be escalated from bronchodilators to steroids as the clinical situation demands, and that would be expressed as "are treated with X, escalating to Y"

@TimR then this sentence is a series of consecutive events. Yeah, that makes the most sense.

I apologise, but all of this is wrong in my opinion. I thought about it a little more. in fact, this sentence is an ‘adverb manner’. and it answers the question ‘how’. that is, it is not cause and effect and it is not a series of consecutive events. new minister friends may think this way. as a doctor, I thought this way because I know the drugs and the procedure.

I'm no medic, but I asked Google Gemini is asthma more likely to be treated with steroids first, then with bronchodilators if steroids don't effect a cure, or with bronchodilators first, then steroids if necessary? It replied with Asthma is more likely to be treated with
inhaled corticosteroids (steroids) first, then with bronchodilators if needed. Here's why... Which may all be rubbish, and it's a bit irrelevant here, since all we're concerned with is what the actual cited text means, not the medical truth of the matter, or what kind of typos might be involved.

...and I really don't think "a cause-effect sentence" is a useful concept here, given that the starting point is asthma and chronic obstructive pulmonary disease are two possible causes of tachypnea (where the treatment of those diseases my cause further things to happen).

increasing not escalating, gees.

@emilywenly The sentence is incomplete. The complete sentence reads : "Respiratory causes such as asthma or chronic obstructive pulmonary disease are treated with short- or long-term bronchodilators, escalating the use of steroids and adjuncts based on clinical discretion, which should correct the tachypnea."

OP's query:

Respiratory causes such as asthma or chronic obstructive pulmonary disease are treated with short- or long-term bronchodilators, escalating the use of steroids and adjuncts based on clinical discretion.
What is meant by ‘escalating’ in this sentence?

When I searched the net, I found that the sentence is incomplete, which can lead to different interpretations. The sentence doesn't end at clinical discretion but there is a clause, "which should correct the tachypnea". The complete sentence is:

Respiratory causes such as asthma or chronic obstructive pulmonary disease are treated with short- or long-term bronchodilators, escalating the use of steroids and adjuncts based on clinical discretion, which should correct the tachypnea.
Tachypnea - Sharon B. Park

Medical terminology meanings:

Bronchodilators: Medications that make breathing easier by relaxing lung muscles and widening the airways (bronchi).
Escalating / Treatment escalation: Increasing the complexity or intensity of care in disease management, especially when usual treatment needs to be enhanced.
Clinical discretion: Medical professionals’ use of judgment and experience to decide the best treatment approach.
Tachypnea: Rapid breathing, typically considered a symptom and focus of medical evaluation.

The sentence is elliptical, where  "are treated with" applies to both the clauses:

short- or long-term bronchodilators
escalating the use of steroids and adjuncts based on clinical discretion

The phrase  "escalating the use of steroids and adjuncts based on clinical discretion" means that doctors may increase treatment intensity by adding or adjusting steroids and adjunct medications based on the patient’s condition and needs.

It means this:
“Respiratory causes such as asthma or chronic obstructive pulmonary disease are treated with short- or long-term bronchodilators, and by escalating the use of steroids and adjuncts based on clinical discretion.”
This is a poorly constructed sentence, but this is the correct reading, because bronchodilators are not steroids. Rather, steroids are added to the bronchodilator treatment as needed.


[Respiratory causes such as asthma or chronic obstructive pulmonary disease are treated with short- or long-term bronchodilators], escalating the use of steroids and adjuncts based on clinical discretion.

This construction has similar meaning as one using a relative clause:

[Respiratory causes such as asthma or chronic obstructive pulmonary disease are treated with short- or long-term bronchodilators], which escalates the use of steroids and adjuncts based on clinical discretion.

where the relative pronoun has the entire precedent clause as antecedent.
Here escalate takes the usual meaning of increase or intensify.
The use of gerund-participles as in this case

allows us to say the same thing as a relative clause, starting with who, which or that, but with fewer words.

BBC

We can also say the same thing by starting a new sentence without a wh- word: This [treatment] escalates the use of steroids...

then we can say that this sentence is a cause-effect sentence, right?

How does the use of bronchodilators increase steroidal use? That is what transitive escalate would mean there. I'm pretty sure what is needed there is the intransitive formulation, "escalating to", which could be paraphrased as "including more drastic therapies if the clinical situation warrants them".

Thanks, @FumbleFingers.  Agreed.  The main clause is rather long, and splitting the sentence may be a good idea.
